# Resizing LVM Partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, lvm, resizing

I'm trying to resize a couple of my LVM partitions. I have one that is 850GB (/dev/mapper/cl-home) and one that is 50GB (/dev/mapper/cl-root). I'd like to make it so that cl-home is 750GB and cl-root is 150GB. I resized the partitions so that if I use system-config-lvm and look at the size cl-home appears as 750GB and cl-root is 150GB. However, if I do a df -h, both cl-home and cl-root appear as their old sizes (850GB and 50GB respectively). How do I make it so that I am able to see and use the resized partitions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**NB**: As Zoredache points out in the comment, when you are *shrinking* things, you *must* first resize the filesystem, then the underlying block devices, otherwise you will likely lose data.

In general, resizing a block device does not resize any *filesystem* that may be resident on your block device.  So, if you used `lvresize` to resize a logical volume, you would then need to use the `resize2fs` command (for ext[34] filesystems) to resize the filesystem.  The `-r` flag to `lvresize` will do this for you.

If you have actually resized a *partition*, which would correspond to an LVM "physical volume" (or "PV"), you would need to:

- `pvresize` the physical volume to expose the additional space to your volume group, and then
- `lvresize` the logical volume, and finally
- resize the filesystem (which maybe you did in the previous step with `-r`)

Comment: `if you used lvresize to resize a logical volume, ... then need` - Since he is reducing the size of a volume, he better be doing that in the other order, or he will face some serious risk of corruption or data loss.  When reducing, you need to **resize the fs first**, then reduce the logical volume.  Oh, and with any operation like this, always make a full backup first.

Comment: Zoredache++, I hadn't fully grokked that he was shrinking things. MUST READ SLOWER.